# In Google Sheets, how can I find text within a range of cells?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a range of cells in one column, some contain text and some are blank cells. I want to search the range for the first occurrence of a word. I know that it's possible to combine Index and Match functions to find exact text within a range of cells. But I need to search for partial matches. I've tried mixing using the Search function, but it doesn't seem to accept a range. How can I search a range for the first partial text match? I only want to use formulas, not script.

Answer (score 18):

The `search` function can be applied to a range using `arrayformula` wrapper:

```
=arrayformula(search("str", C2:F9))
```

This returns a bunch of `#value!` errors where no match is found, or the position of substring when it's found. A more readable output is produced with

```
=arrayformula(if(iserror(search("str", C2:F9)), , C2:F9))
```

This leaves non-matches blank, and returns the actual cell content where there is a match. Or you could put `row(C2:F9)` at the end to get the row numbers, etc.

Comment: If you use row(c2:f9) then the result may have empty cells. to remove those empty cells, FILTER fucntion can be applied as shown here https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/72621/how-to-skip-blank-cells-when-copying-a-range-from-source-to-destination-by-formu

Answer (score 3):

We can simply use [vlookup](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) or [match](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) formula to find a string from a specific range

Vlookup example:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, $B$2:$B, 1, FALSE)
```

Match example:

```
=MATCH("Sunday",A2:A9,0)

=MATCH(DATE(2012,1,1),A2:F2)
```